# Type C schengen visa overlap

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I currently hold Schengen visa type C multiple entries valid for one year (from 10 December 2014 - 09 December 2015). So far I have two entries: 18 December 2014 - 11 January 2015 (25 days) and 25 March 2015 - 21 April 2015 (28 days). The total stay is now 53 days. I believe the half year (180 days) for my visa is at 15 June 2015. Now, I planned to stay in Germany from the 26th of May - 6th of September. That would make 104 days. However, it is an overlap between two half year as my first half year ends on the 15th of June. My question is, is it possible to combine the stays from two half year allowance together? Or is it that I must stay in EU zone for only 90 days with or without the overlap?

Comment: What's your citizenship? If you are from Antigua and Barbuda, The Bahamas, Barbados, Brazil, Saint Kitts and Nevis, Mauritius, or Seychelles, you might be able to benefit from a quirk in the rules. Otherwise, you cannot stay more than 90 days at once on a regular type C Schengen visa, under any circumstances.

Comment: My citizenship is Thai.

Comment: Then you are out of luck, sorry. Do check the calculator in DCTLib's answer for details but 104 is definitely too long.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that within any 180 days time windows, you must not be present in the Schengen zone for more than 90 calendar days. It does not matter when it is "half time" - if there is any period of 180 consecutive days in which you would be present for 91 days or more, you would overstay your visa.

The EU has a Schengen visa calculator that allows you to check if your plans are OK here:

http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html

Note that your visa may also have a limit on the overall number of days spent in the Schengen area, which you must take in consideration in addition to the 90/180 rule.

Comment: (+1) In principle, a one-year multiple-entry visa should not have any extra restriction beyond the 90/180 rule (it's explicitly ruled out by the regulation). But we regularly have questions about strange two-entry visas from Scandinavia so you never know…